# Eclipse needs to be restarted to see the changes made to an application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I start Eclipse I can run the Android application using the `Run As > Android Application` but then I make editions to the app and save but in the emulator the app is not updated. I thought there was *hot deployment* (as mentioned [SO question1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728588/410975)), but I close the emulator and restart it. But if I try to run the app using `Run As` for a second time within Eclipse it gets stuck at 27% (as discussed in this [SO question2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5118713/410975)), and I use the recommended solution of `Window>AVD Manager>Start`. The problem I am having with this approach is that modifications to the application made while the AVD is running are not updated to the emulator when the application is later restarted, and even restarting the emulator does not propagate the changes made. The changes are only registered when Eclipse is restarted.

Could this be an error with Eclipse? It is 3.6.2 with Android Development Toolkit 18... I would not mind any solution that allows me to not have to restart Eclipse each time I want to run the new version of the program. I checked for software updates before this post was made.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Project->Clean before launching a second time?

Comment: I think the best solution is to have a real device for testing. I use my HTC Desire and Asus Transformer Prime as testdevices, and it works flawlessy. Also the emulator is painfully slow. I can go cook dinner while waiting for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have hit the same problem as well, and solved it by building from the commandline using ant.  Honestly the best thing is to do as much from the commandline as possible.  I've found it to be much faster and less error prone than doing everything in Eclipse.

Comment: interesting. I am working under windows, so I am not sure if that is possible.

Comment: I had it working on Windows, just had to install ant on there.  I switched to a mac a few months ago, so I forget the exact steps, but I believe this link has everything you need to do: http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2010/06/installing-ant-for-windows-7.html.

I remember it being pretty easy to do.  Once you do that, you just need to run the 'android' command to add the necessary files to build with ant (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)